# Find count of posts where the first comment were made at X range dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord

I have a problem trying to make this query,

I have 2 tables, lets call them posts and comments:

Posts:

| id | title | is_public |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | post 1 | true |
| 2 | post 2 | true |
| 3 | post 3 | false |

Comments:

| id | post_id | text | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | comment 1 | 2021-01-01 |
| 2 | 1 | comment 2 | 2021-01-02 |
| 3 | 2 | comment 3 | 2021-01-03 |
| 4 | 2 | comment 4 | 2021-01-04 |
| 5 | 3 | comment 5 | 2021-01-04 |

What I want to calculate is the count of posts where its first comment was created between 2 dates and when the variable 'is_public' of the posts is true.

I already made a query ordering the comments by date and grouping by post_id, but i'm not sure if its right:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (SELECT distinct on (c.post_id) c.post_id, c.created_at
FROM comments c
INNER JOIN posts p
ON p.id = c.post_id
WHERE c.created_at >= '2021-01-01' AND c.created_at <= '2021-01-04' AND p.is_public = true
ORDER BY c.post_id, c.created_at ASC) as q1;
```

**Expected result with dates '2021-01-01' and '2021-01-04':**

2

**Expected result with dates '2021-01-02' and '2021-01-04':**

1

Annyone can help me to confirm my solution or proposing another one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to calculate is the count of posts where its first comment was created between 2 dates and when the variable 'is_public' of the posts is true

This is basically filtering:

```
select count(*)
from posts p
where p.is_public and
      (select min(c.created_at)
       from comments c
       where c.post_id = p.id
      ) between '2021-01-01' and '2021-01-04';
```

Comment: thank you!, I think this is what I wanted!